# Simple End-of-input Error - Rails Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, syntax-error

I'm getting a `syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input` error. I checked some other posts that had the same problem but I have no if or conditional statement that needs closing. Just a simple form_tag that I believe is closed properly with some field tags sporadically spread throughout the code. Any help great appreciated! Thank you!

```
<%= render 'partials/header' %>
<%= render :partial => "partials/feature", locals: {type: @full_feature} %>
<div id="fineart-full-page">
    <div id="search-panel">
        <% form_tag('/fineart', method: :get) %>
            <div id="top-round">
            </div>
            <div id="main-row">
                <div id="column-1">
                    <div id="row-1">
                    Power Search
                    </div>
                    <div id="row-2">
                    <%= text_field_tag 'q' %>
                    </div>
                    <div id="row-3">
                    Search Keyword, Title, Artist,<br>Subject, Location, & JTG#
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="column-2">
                    <%= submit_tag %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="bottom-round">
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `form_tag` is missing the `do` that should follow it when specifying a code block. It should look like so:

```
<% form_tag('/fineart', method: :get) do %>
  ....
<% end %>
```

Hope it helps!